# PDF compression with PDFBox Java

Tags: java, pdf, compression, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to create a PDF from merging many similar PDF files together. Typically this can range from a dozen to a few thousand PDF's being merged into one. The resultant PDF can be very large (> 500mb).

Tried the code below to try and compress the merged PDF further, but addCompression seems to now be deprecated in later releases.

```
PDDocument compressedPdf;
compressedPdf = PDDocument.load("c:/Temp/Merged.pdf");
PDStream stream = new PDStream(compressedPdf);
stream.addCompression();
compressedPdf.save("C:/Temp/Compressed.pdf");
compressedPdf.close();
```

Whats the best way to do this efficiently, without comprising quality ?

Additionally, are there any better alternatives to PDFBox? Would rather use a non commercial library.

Thanks

Comment: `new PDStream(compressedPdf);` just creates an empty PDStream. There is no straightforward solution to compress a PDF file. One would have to look at the result file to see whether there's really something common.

Comment: It might help to explain why you're merging so many files. Is it to create one huge print job? If so, then check whether the files are tagged. This can get very big and isn't needed for printing. Call `doc.getDocumentCatalog().setStructureTreeRoot(null);` before saving.

Comment: oc.getDocumentCatalog().setStructureTreeRoot(null) didn't make any difference to the file size

Comment: Another thing to try: `doc.getDocument().setIsXRefStream(true); if (doc.getVersion() < 1.5f) doc.setVersion(1.5f);` (even if it works, it will have only a slight improvement)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: I have tried both of the solution, pdDocument1.getDocumentCatalog().setStructureTreeRoot(null);
            pdDocument1.getDocument().setIsXRefStream(true);
            if (pdDocument1.getVersion() < 1.5f)
                pdDocument1.setVersion(1.5f);
And nothing worked for me.
Do we still have compression support in pdfbox 3.x

Comment: Yes compression is even better in 3.0.* . Please create a separate question with a working testcase, or open a ticket in JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX . If you have to register a new user, then mention it here so we know you're not a spammer.